# Setting up a central logging package for multiple applications

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

Say we create a package called 'my-loggers' that can be reused, that looks like this:

```
import bunyan = require('bunyan');
const loggers = {};

export const getLogger = function(name, config){

   if(loggers[name]){
     return loggers[name];
   }

  return loggers[name] = bunyan.createLogger(config);

};
```

then in each application, we do:

```
npm install -S my-loggers
```

then we use the logger like this:

```
import * as MyLoggers from 'my-loggers';
import config = require('../my-app-config');
const log = MyLoggers.getLogger('my-app', config.logging);
```

the problem is it really requires 3 lines of code to retrieve the logger for each file in each app.

I am trying to figure out a way to create a single package that can retrieve a logger for any file in any app, and I am trying to

1. cut everything down to just one LoC.
2. I am also trying to avoid relative paths.

I cannot think of a solution that involves 1 logging package for all our apps. The only thing I can think of is either a separate logging package per app (which is kinda lame), or doing a trick where we symlink some code from our project into node_modules, upon npm install, which allows us to avoid relative paths.

Anyone know of a good way to solve this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have a solution. We can just do this:

```
import log from 'my-loggers/app1'
import log from 'my-loggers/app2'
import log from 'my-loggers/app3'
```

that way we can store different loggers in the same package.